What denominations have published prophecies about lost Scripture?
The existence of Holy Scripture not contained in the present-day Bible editions can hardly be debated against, since there are numerous references to Scriptures we do not have within the Scriptures that we do have. It is understood that this may be partly a question of what qualifies as canon, or of mistranslation, corruption or degradation of extant texts, but perhaps mostly of documents that simply have not been found, and might even no longer exist in physical form. Apocryphal documents quoted in canonical Scripture are an example of extant, partially translated and possibly corrupted texts that contain some truths corroborated in Scripture but on the whole might not read entirely like Scripture, although this question is not so much about Apocryphal writings as it is about content that could be clearly identified as Scriptural. It can be identified as such since it has been alluded to, referenced, or even directly quoted within Holy Scripture as being of a similar nature, written by the same prophets or those having the same calling, etc. Examples may include the Book of the Wars of the Lord referenced in Numbers 21:13–14, Paul's lost letters, the Book of Gad the Seer, the Book of Nathan the Prophet, the prophecy of Ahijah, the visions of Iddo the seer, and many more.
Knowing what I know of the tremendous doctrinal and instructional value of the Pauline epistles, and the remarkable visions and prophecies of ancient prophets and seers, it would obviously be a great boon to any Christian library to have access to, or even further hints of what is contained in those lost books of Scripture. Having two or three more Pauline epistles could even radically improve general understanding of the teachings of Christianity, by triangulating the Doctrine of Jesus Christ more finely, specifying additional verifiable historic details, eliminating ambiguity through cross-referencing of existing texts, and so on.
I believe there are reasons, attested within Scripture, why God does not give us all of His books at once--first and foremost of which is to try our faith. If historians an emperors could not pretend that the accounts of Jesus and His resurrection were merely fiction or accounts of some obscure extremist carpenter who died a tragic death due to his opposition against religious leaders, due to the overwhelming nature and number of additional highly public witnesses, we might suppose a greater proportion of the Earth's population would be converted.
What is an overview of Christian denominations that (1) acknowledge the existence of lost Scripture, and (2) have some published prophetic statements or other doctrine about the missing books and passages of Scripture?
Finally, (3) how are they doctrinally bound (if at all) to treat such Scripture?

The standard canon of the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints ("Mormons") contains, in addition to the standard Protestant Bible, the Book of Mormon, The Pearl of Great Price, and the Doctrine and Covenants. The Book of Mormon is believed to contain books which were re-discovered by Joseph Smith after having been buried for centuries. The Pearl of Great Price contains, among its contents, the Book of Abraham and the Book of Moses, which are believed to be genuine lost scriptures that have been rediscovered. None of these books are specifically cited by the Bible, but they meet the criteria for being identified as genuine lost scriptures that have been recovered and deemed canonical.

Were there prophecies that these scriptures would be rediscovered? Because otherwise I don't really see how this is an answer.
